# How to collect metrics from services running on docker containers using collectd, telegraph or similar tools

Tags: docker, metrics, influxdb, collectd

What is the common practice to get metrics from services running inside Docker containers, using tools like CollectD, or InfluxDD Telegraph?

These tools are normally configured to run as agents in the system and get metrics from localhost.

I have read collectd docs and some plugins allow to get metrics from remote systems so I could have for example, an NGINX container and then a collectd container to get the metrics, but there isnt a simpler way?

Also, I dont want to use Supervisor or similar tools to run more that "1 process per container".

I am thinking about this in conjunction with a System like DC/OS or Kubernetes.

What do you think?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am running more than one process per container because Kubernetes comes packaged with InfluxDB, thus telegraf is the consistent solution.